# Java Sorting based on Enum constants

Tags: java, sorting, enums

We have an enum

```
enum listE {
    LE1,
    LE4,
    LE2,
    LE3
}
```

Furthermore, we have a list that contains the strings `["LE1","LE2","LE3","LE4"]`. Is there a way to sort the list based on the enum defined order (not the natural `String` order).

The sorted list should be `["LE1", "LE4", "LE2", "LE3"]`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[`Enum<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) implements `Comparable<E>` via the natural order of the enum (the order in which the values are declared). If you just create a list of the enum values (instead of strings) via parsing, then sort that list using `Collections.sort`, it should sort the way you want. If you need a list of strings again, you can just convert back by calling `name()` on each element.

Comment: what about reverse order?

Comment: @IgorG. call reversed() method on it after sorting

Comment: @IgorG. you can do Collections.sort(enumList, Comparator.reverseOrder())

Comment: what if the stream is of a pair? Any easy way to do it?

Comment: @Ali_Nass: I suggest you ask a new question with a complete example of *exactly* what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

`values()` method returns in the order in which it is defined.

```
enum Test{
  A,B,X,D
}

for(Test t: Test.values()){
  System.out.println(t);
}
```

**Output**

```
A
B
X
D
```

Comment: This does not help with sorting by declaration order.

Answer (score 8):

I used following to sort my `List<theEnum>`  in an ascending order, and it worked fine for me.

```
Collections.sort(toSortEnumList, new Comparator<theEnum>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(theEnum o1, theEnum o2) {
                    return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what was asked for: Sorting _not_ lexicographically but by declaration order.

Answer (score 8):

If you want different sort order then provided in `Enum` class and you cannot modify it, just assign `int` to your enum fields and compare it:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<ListE> {

    @Override
    public int compare(ListE o1, ListE o2) {
        return Integer.compare(getAssignedValue(o1), getAssignedValue(o2));
    }

    int getAssignedValue(ListE listE) {
        switch (listE) {
            case LE2:
                return 0;
            case LE1:
                return 1;
            case LE4:
                return 2;
            case LE3:
                return 3;
            default:
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

}
```

and then use

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());
```

Answer (score 7):

Every enum constant has an [ordinal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) value corresponding to its position in the enum declaration. You can write a comparator for your strings using the ordinal value of the corresponding enum constant.

Answer (score 6):

Jon's answer is correct per the specification:

> Enum implements Comparable via the natural order of the enum (the order in which the values are declared).

However, I wanted to leave a Java8 example in case somebody wants to map string values to an enum and sort by the enum order. With that you can map your strings to the enum, sort using the default comparable, and then map it back using a `toString`. This leaves you with something like this:

```
enum listE {
    LE1,
    LE4,
    LE2,
    LE3
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("LE1", "LE2", "LE3", "LE4");

    System.out.println("Original List: " + originalList);

    List<String> sortedList = originalList.stream()
                                          .map(listE::valueOf)
                                          .sorted(listE::compareTo)
                                          .map(listE::toString)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("Sorted List: " + sortedList);
}
```

The result would be:

- Original List: [LE1, LE2, LE3, LE4]
- Sorted List: [LE1, LE4, LE2, LE3]

Answer (score 4):

you should probably look at the ordinal() method of the enum, it returns an Integer of the position the enum type appears in the enum class, so in your case LE1 = 0, LE4 = 1, etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    public String studentName;

    public Student(String name,DayInWeek weekDay){
        this.studentName = name;
        this.studentDays = weekDay;
    }

    public enum DayInWeek {
        SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
    }
    public DayInWeek studentDays;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s1) {
        if(s1.studentDays.ordinal() < this.studentDays.ordinal())
            return 1;
        else if(s1.studentDays.ordinal() > this.studentDays.ordinal())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This compareTo function fails its contract: "`sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all x and y", which fails for the case where `x==y`, resp. in this case `this==s1`.  
Also, the `this!=s1` case is easier and less error-prone to implement as `return this.studentDays.compareTo(s1.studentDays)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

add to enum field(sorted field)

like

```
enum MyEnum{
 private String sorted;
 MyEnum(String sorted){
  this.sorted = sorted;
 }
 String getSorted(){
  return this.sorted;
 }
}
```

Use `TreeSet`

Implement `Comparator` using `MyEnum.sorted` filed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method you can add to your enumeration to get an array of sorted enumerated constants:

- Where Element is the name of your Enumeration
- Where the enumerations are sorted by their toString

  ```
  public static Element[] getSortedValues(){
      return Stream.of(values()).sorted((o1,o2)->
      {
          return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
      }).
      toArray(Element[]::new);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to sort by ordinal you can use `valueOf` to convert the string and add these to an EnumSet (which is sorted by ordinal)

Otherwise you can sort the values based on an attribute of the enum. (This can be more robust and not dependent of the order the enums are declared) Use valueOf and write a custom Comparator.