# Comparable Class Java

Tags: java, class, methods, comparable

I have this class using enum types for a deck.
What would be the most efficient way to make this class Comparable to sort the cards into ascending order?
Also is it possible to compare two card face values in a method if they are enum types? (for example return the difference or something?)
Thanks.

```
public class Card {

public enum Rank {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, 
                    JACK, QUEEN, KING}
public enum Suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES}

private final Rank rank; 
private final Suit suit; 

private Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int compareTo(Card c) {
    Card aCard = (Card)c;
    int rankComparison = rank.compareTo(aCard.rank);
    return rankComparison != 0 ? rankComparison : suit.compareTo(aCard.suit);
}

public Rank rank(){
    return rank; 
}
public Suit suit(){
    return suit; 
}

public String toString(){ 
    return "The " + rank + " of " + suit + "."; 
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a perfectly reasonable `compareTo` implementation there. The only thing that's missing is to add `implements Comparable<Card>` after `public class Card`.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you should change your class declaration to `public class Card implements Comparable<Card>`

Comment: Just add `Card implements Comparable<Card>`, your implementation is fine except superflous `aCard` variable.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very got at describing.
Ah, yes, i need to add the 'implements Comparable<Card>'
How would you go about creating a method to actually compare two values, for example, 3 and 7 values which returns a difference of 4 as they are enums?.

Comment: deep search on doku try to get knowledge.

Comment: `compareTo` shouldn't return the difference between two objects. It should return a positive integer, a negative integer or zero depending on if this enum is greater than, less than or equal to the specified object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int compareTo(Card c) {
    int rankComparison = rank.compareTo(c.rank);
    return rankComparison != 0 ? rankComparison : suit.compareTo(c.suit);
}
```

Try this, just make the class implement the `Comparable` interface. Be aware that enums are compared in the order they are declared.

See,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)

To test this you can write JUnit tests with different cards, for example,

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    Card aceOfSpades = new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.SPADES);
    Card fourOfClubs = new Card(Rank.FOUR, Suit.CLUBS);

    assertTrue(aceOfSpades.compareTo(fourOfClubs) > 0));
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: Enums are comparable through the order the members are given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Whats the quickest way to test this compareTo?

Comment: @shardy added a test for you :)