# Converting C# to Java, how do I handle IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, java

I've been tasked with converting some C# code to Java. Most of it is fine, but I am having some trouble working out how to translate IEnumerable.

The code I have in C# is this:

```
public IEnumerable<Cat> Reorder(IEnumerable<Cat> catList)
{

  // some logic that reorders the list

}
```

My googling suggested that I should be using `Iterable<Cat>` as an alternative. However, I also stumbled upon something saying you should never have `Iterable<T>` as a return type.

I'm a bit unfamiliar with data structures in Java. What should I be returning, and how would you re-order a collection of objects?

In C#, assuming you don't use linq, you'd create an empty array or List or similar, and add the items in as you repeatedly iterate through them, checking the criteria. Which data structure would I use in Java to achieve this?

Comment: This "something" you've stumbled upon is wrong. There's nothing intrinsically wrong in returning an Iterable.

Comment: Question dogma in all forms.

Comment: @duffymo: Isn't that a dogma on its own? ;-)

Comment: You're a funny man, Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to do with the return value.
Java has no LINQ, so using an `Iterable<T>` other than inside a `foreach` loop is a bit of a PITA. [This blog post](http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2519) describes it in more depth.
The alternative is to return a `Collection<T>`.
Having said that, returning an `Iterable<T>` is not wrong, it just makes it harder to consume the return value in certain scenarios.

In Java you would use an implementation of `List<T>` like `ArrayList<T>` for temporary instances inside methods. When you would want to return that instance from a method, the return type would be the interface `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`.

Comment: I want to pass in a list of objects, and then re-order them based on one of their properties, and then return the ordered list.

Comment: @SLC: I know, you already said that in your question. What do you want to tell me with repeating it here in the comments?

Comment: You asked me in your answer before you edited it :) So do you think I should use `Collection<T>` or `ArrayList<T>`?

Comment: @SLC: You must have dreamed that :) I never ask in answers. I guess I would use `Collection` as return type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still pretty confused about the differences between `List` `ArrayList` and `Collection` and why I can't do `new List<Cat>();` though.

Comment: @SLC: In Java `List<T>` and `Collection<T>` are interfaces, equivalent to C#'s `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>`. `ArrayList<T>` is an implementation of the `List<T>` interface, equivalent to C#'s `List<T>` class. You can't create an instance of `List<T>` in Java, beause - just as in C# - you can only create instances of concrete classes, not of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like Collections.sort(list); if you implement a Interface Comparable at your objects (similiar can be done with c# and the IComparer)

"add the items in as you repeatedly iterate through them," I hope you don't really mean what I'm thinking you mean... There are a hell lot of sorting algorithms.

Comment: Yeah this is also my recommendation :) . Follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with Iterable, *when you need to use it*.

However, considering what the code above tells me, I think you'd be better going with ***java.util.Collection*** or ***java.util.List*** (the latter if catList is definitely a list of cats).

The way of reordering actually depends on the ordering requirements. It's probably as simple as using *Collections.sort(List list)*

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you recommend Collection or List?

Comment: @BuhBuh Well, the parameter of the method is name _catList_. That tells me (assuming the naming conventions used are consistent and sane) they're dealing with a list or at least a collection of objects. `java.util.List` is the ultimate choice for dealing with lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should identify the data structure you need. 
Basically the 3 great data structure families are:

- **List**: An ordered index-based collection;
- **Set**: A collection that contains no duplicate elements;
- **Map**: A key-value based collection (A dictionnary in C#). Not adapted here in this precise case.

Depending on what you need, you should return `List<Cat>` or `Set<Cat>`.