# Order a list of objects

Tags: java, list, enums

I am making a program that simulates a card game. I have a class `Card` that represents a playing card:

```
//suit types
public enum Suits{
    SPADES,
    CLUBS,
    HEARTS,
    DIAMONDS
}

//value types
public enum Values{
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX,
    SEVEN,
    EIGHT,
    NINE,
    TEN,
    JACK,
    QUEEN,
    KING,
    ACE, 
}

private Suits suit;
private Values value;

//Card constructor
public Card(Values value, Suits suit){
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

In my game class I have a players hand represented by a `List` of `Cards`:

```
public List<Card> playerHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Is there a way that I can sort the players hand by  my enum `Values`? Meaning if a players hand is:

TEN, ACE, TWO, FIVE

After ordering it would be:

TWO, FIVE, TEN, ACE

My conditions would be `Ace` is always high, and `Suit` doesn't matter. I know ordering Lists are trivial I just don't know how to do it for an `Object` based on an `enum`

Comment: Maybe you can create an associative array and use it in a function valueOf(string) (`valueOf(TEN) === 10`, `valueOf("JACK") === 11` and so on...). And then use it to sort your hand.

Comment: Implement Comparable on class Card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Sorting based on Enum constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants)

Comment: For implementation of Comparable or similar, consider using Enum.ordinal().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

for sorting. As for comparator:

```
new Comparator<Card>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Card x, Card y) {
    return x.getValue().compareTo(y.getValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Enums have a default ordering, i.e. they implement `Comparable` and thus you can just sort a list of enums or call `ACE.compareTo( TEN )` in some `Comparator`. Note that the order of the enum values is the order of definition in the enum class (based on ordinal, see next paragraph), i.e. in your case `TWO` < `THREE` < `FOUR` etc.

Additionally enums have an ordinal, i.e. the index of the enum value inside the definition. In your case `TWO` would have the ordinal 0, `THREE` the ordinal 1 etc.

In order to sort your cards, you could use a `Comparator` (or implement `Comparable<Card>`) like this:

```
class CardComparator implements Comparator<Card> {
  public int compare( Card lhs, Card rhs) {
    //suit would be relevant otherwise you'd end up with spades 10, hearts 10, spades jack etc.
    //thus sort by suit first to keep the cards of a suit together
    int r = lhs.suit.compareTo( rhs.suit ); 

    if( r == 0) { //same suit    
      r = lhs.value.compareTo( rhs.value );
    }
    return r;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set a value for each of the `Suits` and `Values`, so that I can compare them to one another. For example:

```
public enum Suits{
    SPADES(1),
    CLUBS(2),
    HEARTS(3),
    DIAMONDS(4);

    private int value;

    private Suits(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and the `Values` enum:

```
public enum Values{
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9),
    TEN(10),
    JACK(11),
    QUEEN(12),
    KING(13),
    ACE(14);

    private int value;

    private Values(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement a `Comparator` for the `Cards`:

```
public class CardsComparator implements Comparator<Card> {
    public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
        //implementation based on the values of Suits and Values.
        if (c1.getSuits().getValue() == c2.getSuits.getValue()) {
            return c1.getValue().compareTo(c2.getValue());
        } else {
            return c1.getSuits().compareTo(c2.getSuits());
        }
    }
}
```

and apply an instance of the Comparator to sort your `List<Card>`:

```
Collections.sort(listOfCards, new CardsComparator());
```

Comment: Unnecessary field 'value' inside enums.

Comment: It's not unnecessary, because if you change the order of the `Suits` and use ordinal you'll get conceptually wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the interface Comparable. You would have to redefine the compareTo method for your Card class and it would then allow you to do something like :

```
Card a = ...;
Card b = ...;

if(a.compareTo(b) <= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Or even :

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html