# Re-order two values from an alphabetically ordered list. Enum/Comparataor

Tags: java, sorting, enums, comparator, comparable

coded list of values A,B,C,D,E,F,G....
I want D to be placed before C while iterating through the list in the JSP.

I'm open for enum or to use comparators.

Currently the enum SortOrder is different object from the Comparable which i currently have.

So how can i deal with this below code.

```
//override

    public int compareTo(Alphabets) {

        return name.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.getName().toLowerCase());
      }
```

I've tried

```
private SortOrder so
     public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = so.values().toString();
      }
```

But it throws "The static method values() from the type SortOrder should be accessed in a static way"

Please help me.

I've tried stackoverflow and found this, which is close, but not enough:
[Java Sorting based on Enum constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants)

Edit: sorry to confuse everyone, the above question is just a representation of what my issue is. The words which i have for A,B,C,.. have a different presentation in my code.
I have a list of brand names for a product, where i want to re-order the list.

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more of your code (at least of the `SortOrder` class) to understand the thrown exception. Also, can you clarify the expected sorting rule ? Is it _sort values in case-insensitive alphabetically ascending order, except when there is a numerical suffix, have the suffix in descending order_ ?

Comment: Is D2 the only case, or it is that any letter-number should be sorted in this special way?

Comment: Edit: sorry to confuse everyone, the above question is just a representation of what my issue is. The words which i have for A,B,C,.. have a different presentation in my code. I have a list of brand names for a product, where i want to re-order the list.
@Volune
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure I understand your question, but if I do, here are two solutions:

#### With enum

Smallest solution, limited to possible names for enum values. [demo](http://ideone.com/vzE71P)

```
enum SortOrderEnum {
    A, B, D, C, E, F;
}
```

Sort with

```
Collections.sort(testData, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return SortOrderEnum.valueOf(s1).compareTo(SortOrderEnum.valueOf(s2));
    }
});
```

### Without enum

You can put any string you want, I didn't see the point of using an enum in this solution. We put the expected index for each string in a static map. [demo](http://ideone.com/2bzzpm)

```
public class SortOrder {
    public static final Map<String, Integer> SORT_ORDER = initializeSortOrder();

    private static Map<String, Integer> initializeSortOrder() {
        List<String> orderedStrings = Arrays.asList(
                "A",
                "B",
                "D",
                "C",
                "E",
                "F"
        );
        Map<String, Integer> indexByString = new HashMap<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < orderedStrings.size(); ++index) {
            indexByString.put(orderedStrings.get(index), index);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(indexByString);
    }
}
```

Sort with

```
Collections.sort(testData, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return SORT_ORDER.get(s1).compareTo(SORT_ORDER.get(s2));
    }
});
```

Note that this is an example of how to fill the map. You can (better) fill the string->index map from a configuration file.

You can also not put the map in a static variable if that causes problems for you.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you're happy with the default compareTo, but you want just a little bit of difference, right?

```
if (this.name.equals("D2") && that.name.equals("D1")) return -1;
if (this.name.equals("D1") && that.name.equals("D2")) return 1;
return super.compareTo(that);
```