# How to sort my list object based on order of Enum values

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum EnumProductConfig
{
    Color,
    Fold,
    Edge,
    Hem,
    Lift,
    Tapes,
    Control,
    Clips,    
    Pull,
    Val
}
```

The order of above values in enum is not alphabatical which is totally ok with me.

Now, I have a list with one of the property of type EnumProductConfig. I want to sort my list based on that property (*which is of Enum type*) in the order of appearance in the Enum. I do not want to sort it alphabetically. The order must stay as mentioned in my Enum. Hence all rows with value Color must come first. Followed by Fold etc.

Please advise.

Comment: You have a List<EnumProductConfig> or something like this List<T> where T has one attribute of type EnumProductConfig?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants

Comment: If your enum was instead `public enum EnumProductConfig
{
    Color = 1,
    Fold = 0,
    Edge = 2,
    Hem = 3,
    Lift = 4,
    Tapes = 5,
    Control = 6,
    Clips = 7,    
    Pull = 8,
    Val = 9
}` would you expect `Color` or `Fold` to be first?

Answer (score 0):

In c#, an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) is a group of numeric value constants.
If not specified, the enum's underlying type is `int`:

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char. The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int

And every enum member gets a value from `0` to `n`, where `n` is the number of members -1:

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

Since you didn't specify neither the underlying type nor the values, your enum is equivalent to:

```
public enum EnumProductConfig : int
{
    Color = 0,
    Fold = 1,
    Edge = 2,
    Hem = 3,
    Lift = 4,
    Tapes = 5,
    Control = 6,
    Clips = 7,    
    Pull = 8,
    Val = 9
}
```

This means you can simply order by your `EnumProductConfig` property:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>()
var sorted = list.OrderBy(c => c.ProductConfig);
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/CZJ44813)

Answer (score 0):

```
myData.OrderBy(d => (int)d.ProductConfig).ToList();
```

Should do it. Import `System.Linq`

Enums are really just `int`s anyway, going from zero and increasing by 1. You can also give each value a specific `int` value if you want to.

Also, you should not prefix your enum type with the word enum as it is against the Microsoft naming guidelines.

Comment: "Enums are really just ints anyway" wrong. Enumns can be byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong. Also, no need to cast to int.

Comment: I only cast to an int so it is clear that the order was intended to be based on the underlying value of the enum. I'm aware it isn't required, I just think it's useful in this instance. It isn't a real cast anyway so it won't slow down the ordering process.