# Java - How do we make a certain object in a set to return at index 0;

Tags: java

Suppose we have a set

```
public Set<CarPartDto> carpart
```

where CarPartDto is

```
public class CarPartDto {

public String type;
public String colour;
public Long torque;
public Long maxSpeed;
public String manufacturer;
```

How do we make a list that return the very first index or index 0 to desired object lets say manufacturer

Expected result like this

```
            "manufacturer": nissan,
            "type": "sedan",
            "colour": "black",
            "torque": 139,
            "maxSpeed": 200,
```

actual result like this

```
            "type": "sedan",
            "colour": "black",
            "torque": 139,
            "maxSpeed": 200,
            "manufacturer": nissan
```

Im new to this field. Please help!

Comment: You have a `Set`. You're talking about making a `List` and indexes. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: return carpart.toArray()[0];

Comment: By first index you mean you want to return `type` first? While printing?

Comment: Where/ How do you get this output? From the toString method of your CarPartDto?

Comment: @ernest_k i want to convert set to list and return the desired object at index 0 of list

Comment: That's easy but was has actual vs expected output to do with this?

Comment: @BlackPearl lets say i want to return manufacturer first

Comment: Can you actually post how you got the above said result? Did you just print it? Please post all the code in context.

Comment: @zd14 The answer depends on what sort implementation you will use. If `TreeSet` please take a look what options for customer comparators you have: http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treeset/sort-by-objects/ and how to write them

Comment: @Eritrean it actually spring web app, so i got it from controller. if its correct xd

Comment: `List<CarPartDto> list = new ArrayList<>(carpart); CarPartDto carpart = list.get(0);`

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: How are you outputting/using the values? Are you just printing them to console?

A Set is not ordered so its impossible to tell which item is printed first. You need an ordered list/set like TreeSet, ConcurrentSkipListSet or ArrayList. But it seems you are talking about the objects IN the set that need to be ordered. In that case the Set is irrelevant and you just need to change your output of the object. For that we need more info on how you print or use the object.

Comment: That output unlikely has anything to do with a `Set`, it is more related to `toString()` of `CarPartDto`.

Comment: It would be best for everyone, if you understood yourself what you wanted to do. Half of what I have read doesn't make any sense. From what you write in the "expected output", then why not write a **single method** to print those variable values for you? Edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I cant post a comment so:

Looks like you want to order the types just simple change your class to

```
public class CarPartDto {

 public String manufacturer;
 public String type;
 public String colour;
 public Long torque;
 public Long maxSpeed;
}
```

or you can make a method(inside your class) than return your desired format object:

```
        public String getCarInfo(){

        return "manufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\ntype: " + type + "\ncolour: "+colour + "\ntorque: " + torque + "\nmaxSpeed: " + maxSpeed;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you rely on the order of your declarations for your output? The better way in indeed to create a method or even better to override the toString() method of your object.

Comment: @Kenny Steegmans I dont , i always make a custom method . But the question was so bad explained that i think he have some code that prints the object , and a simple reorganization just do the trick for him. Should i remove the first part?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the title only, *Java - How do we make a certain object in a set to return at index 0;*
`Set`s in general have no user-friendly order as a design goal, though some implementations do have: `TreeSet` returns its elements in their natural order, `LinkedHashSet` returns its elements in the order they have been inserted.
You can try that with a simple code like

```
Random r=new Random();
Set<Integer> treeset=new TreeSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> linked=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> simple=new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    int n=r.nextInt(100);
    System.out.print(n+", ");
    treeset.add(n);
    linked.add(n);
    simple.add(n);
}
System.out.println();
for(Object i:treeset.toArray())
  System.out.print(i+", ");
System.out.println();
for(Object i:linked.toArray())
  System.out.print(i+", ");
for(Object i:simple.toArray())
  System.out.print(i+", ");
```

(https://ideone.com/Wz3o61 - first line is a bunch of random numbers, second line is `TreeSet`, ordered, third line is `LinkedHashSet`, preserving input order, last line is `HashSet`, having arbitrary order).

So if your problem would be related to `Set`-s (which does not seem to be the case at the time of writing), you could enforce a "first" element by using `LinkedHashSet` and adding that element first, or a more esoteric approach would be choosing/creating an element class with a suitable ordering - perhaps [using an enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants). But the problem is more likely related to printing an object, a `toString()` like method somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you want to print the info of a car as a string. In this case you need to override the toString() method in your CarPartsDto class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Manufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\n" +
            "Type: " + type + ",\n" +
            "Colour: " + colour + ",\n" +
            "Torque: " + torque + ",\n" +
            "MaxSpeed: " + maxSpeed;
}
```

To call this you just need to call your object without any methods or using the toString method.

```
for (CarPartDto car : cars) {
    System.out.println(car);
}
```

Additionally if you need the info in any other form you can also write your own method and return it in any format you need (in this case String):

```
public String returnCarInfo(){
    return "Type: " + type + ",\n" +
            "Colour: " + colour + ",\n" +
            "Torque: " + torque + ",\n" +
            "MaxSpeed: " + maxSpeed + ",\n" +
            "Manufacturer: " + manufacturer;
}
```

and call it using the method.

```
System.out.println(car.returnCarInfo());
```

Hope this helps!