# Only print every other enum value in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, enums

I'm trying to make it so only every other colour is being printed off in my for loop statement but because of the type difference I'm unable to incorporate it in an `if` statement.

```
public enum Example{Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Purple, Brown}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Example colour: Example.values()) {
            if (????) {
                System.out.println(colour);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
Red Green Orange Brown
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Sorting based on Enum constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ordinal()` like

```
for (Example colour : Example.values()) {
    if (colour.ordinal() % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(colour);
    }
}
```

Or, you could use an external variable to hold a count. Something like,

```
int i = 0;
for (Example colour : Example.values()) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(colour);
    }
    i++;
}
```

But this seems like a good place for a traditional `for` loop that increments by `2`. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < Example.values().length; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(Example.values()[i]);
}
```

All three produce your requested output.

Comment: However, `Example.values()` returns a new array each time, so you may not want to call it in a loop.

Comment: @Andy you can use variable, but good point anyway

Comment: @vyacheslav.kislov yes. That's exactly the point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to iterate over every other color:

```
for (int i =0; i< Example.values().length;i+=2){
    System.out.println(Example.values()[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `Example.values()` and print the alternate elements by checking if the index is divisible by 2 (i.e. `index % 2 == 0`).

**Demo using the `Stream` API:**

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

enum Example {
    Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Purple, Brown
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(0, Example.values().length)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println(Example.values()[i]));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Red
Green
Orange
Brown
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CH33GG)

You can use the traditional loops instead of using an `IntStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a loop:

```
boolean toggle = false;
for (Example value : Example.values()) {
  if (toggle ^= true) System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Lol. I was about to comment that this is gross, but then saw who wrote this :D