# Get object from list of objects filtered by property

Tags: java

I have list of objects and I need to get object from that list which satisfies several conditions.
Here is example of object:

```
User {
  id,
  name,
  contact {
    phone,
    email
  },
  city,
  type
}
```

Here is what I have so far, but I want to check is there some cleaner solution

```
List < User > users = getUsersByCity(city);

User user1 = users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.DIRECTOR) && !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty()).findFirst().get();
if (user1 != null) {
    email = user1.getContact().getEmail();
} else {
    User user2 = users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.MANAGER) && !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty()).findFirst().get();
    if (user2 != null) {
        email = user2.getContact().getEmail();
    } else {
        User user3 = users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.ACCOUNTANT) && !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty()).findFirst().get();
        if (user3 != null) {
            email = user3.getContact().getEmail();
        } else {
            User user4 = users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.ASSISTANT) && !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty()).findFirst().get();
            if (user4 != null) {
                email = user4.getContact().getEmail();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so the thing is that it should return email of user but for this order

1. DIRECTOR
2. MANAGER
3. ACCOUNTANT
4. ASSISTANT

if it found email from director that's it, if not than it should try to find from manager,...

Comment: Why not sort by type, then return first email?

Comment: you can use a map <type,email>

Answer (score 2):

I see two approaches to this problem:

In first approach we need to create a **comparator by enum order**. [Example was taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants).

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator< User > {

    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return Integer.compare(getOrder(o1), getOrder(o2));
    }

    private int getOrder(User user) {
        switch (user) {
            case DIRECTOR:
                return 0;
            case MANAGER:
                return 1;
            case ACCOUNTANT:
                return 2;
            case ASSISTANT:
                return 3;
            default:
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Now we can filter all Users by Type, then flatten the stream to Emails, and pick first one:

```
User user  user = users.stream()
.filter(u -> !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty())
.sort(new MyComparator())
.findFirst()
```

Second approach would be with **Stream concatenation**:

```
 Optional<User> user = Stream.of(
    users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.DIRECTOR),
    users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.MANAGER),
    users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.ACCOUNTANT),
    users.stream().filter(u - > u.getType.equals(User.Type.ASSISTANT)
).flatMap(i -> i)
.filter(u -> !u.getContact().getEmail().isEmpty())
.findFirst();
```