# Sorting a collection - Dynamic count of rules and Sort by set of values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, jpa

I'm trying to sort a collection of objects with multiple dynamic set of rules.
Example :
Rule 1 -> Sort by addedDate | Sort Order :  Asc
Rule 2 -> Sort by User Type | Sort Order : 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze' (not ASC or DESC)
Rule 3 -> Sort by Hobby | Sort Order : 'Music', 'Drama', 'Sport' (not ASC or DESC)

I have 2 questions..

1. Since these rules can be dynamic (at one instance Rule 1, Rule 2 and another instance only Rule 3) how do I create dynamic comparators ?
2. Is there a way of sorting can be done using custom sort(not ASC or DESC) order like in Rule 2 and Rule 3 ?

So far I tried sorting via the repository itself, but could not succeed since it only supports Asc and Desc sort order like below.  `repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "colName"));`

Also I've research Java Comparator, but still I could not pass a custom order like in Rule 2 and Rule 3.
Any expertise is much appreciated.

Comment: (No expert here, but ...) Regarding part 2:  `UserType` and `Hobby` suggest use of `Enum`.  A collection of `Enum` can be sorted according to the order in which the values were declared: [See Java Sorting based on Enum constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants/8007155#8007155) .

Comment: I haven't responded to part 1 because I'm not sure what is being asked.  Could you, please, clarify? Maybe add example(s)?